# Store pointer to const into vector of structs

Tags: c++, pointers, avr-gcc, avrdude

I have an issue doing the following:

**Class "A":**

```
    const uint8_t arr1[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, ...};
    const uint8_t arr2[] = {0xA1, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, ...};    

    struct s1 {
         String name;
         uint8_t const * arr;
    };
    std::vector<s1, std::allocator<alloc1>> vect1;
    std::vector<s1>::iterator it = vect1.begin();

   privateMethod1(uint8_t const * ptr) {
      // this method receives pointer correctly, so I can doPrint(ptr)
      s1 myStruct;
      myStruct.name = "name";
      myStruct.arr = ptr;
      vect1.push_back(myStruct);
   }

    myPublicMethod(String arrName) {
        uint8_t const * ptr;
        if(arrName == "A") {
              ptr = arr1;
        } else if(arrName == "B") {
              ptr = arr2;
        }
        privateMethod1(ptr);
    }
```

**Few moments later...**

```
  myPublicMethod2() {
      for(; it < vect1.end(); it++) {
         doPrint(it->arr);
         // here the link between pointers broken, 
         // doPrint() shows me random characters
      }
   }
```

Apparently the problem is to store arr1 or arr2 correctly in myStruct.
Anyone has an idea where I am wrong using pointers?
Thanks

Comment: The problem is first you give us a non valid C++ code ...

Comment: `std::vector<s1, std::allocator<alloc1>> vect1; std::vector<s1>::iterator it = vect1.begin();` -- This compiled?  The iterator is for a different `vector` type.  That's one reason why `auto` was introduced in C++ 11.

Comment: What is _String_ definition ? What is doPrint definition ? What do you execute before to call `myPublicMethod2()` ?

Comment: Hi @bruno, thanks for being curious ! The stack trace is the following: 1. myPublicMethod(). 2. myPublicMethod2().         doPrint() - that is a kind of printBMP(), as far as arr1 & arr2 are encoded bitmaps.

Comment: @paulmckenzie, thanks! Could you give an example what is wrong and how do I use auto here. The code is compiled with iterator

Comment: @Sergio `std::vector<s1, std::allocator<alloc1>> vect1; auto it = vect1.begin();`

Answer (score 1):

You give us a non valid C++ code, it contains plenty of errors.

You miss to give us the definition of String and alloc1

You miss to give us the execution you did, typically the argument of *myPublicMethod*

So to answer you we need to use a magic crystal ball

One possibility is `(arrName == "A")` and `(arrName == "B")` are false so you do not initialize ptr. These tests returns false for instance when the definition of String is `typedef const char * String;`

Comment: 1. myPublicMethod(“A”); 2. myPublicMethod2();  this is how it’s executed

Comment: **what is the definition of String** ? We use (better to say _lost_) time for you, can you have the politeness to answer to our question ?

Comment: dude, honestly I never require your precious time, neither someones else. I guess is a free will to answer and spend your time helping someone when his/her stack overflowed. So if this is not your job to answer on noobs' questions I have had my politeness. Mery Christmas anyways. – Sergio yesterday

Answer (score 0):

So, I do figured this out. The following code is close to reality example which I was posting earlier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

const uint8_t arr1[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00};
const uint8_t arr2[] = {0xA1, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00};

class A {
public:
    struct s1 {
        std::string name;
        uint8_t const * arr;
    };
    std::vector<s1, std::allocator<s1>> vect1;

    void myPublicMethod(std::string arrName, std::string name) {
        uint8_t const * ptr;
        if(arrName == "A") {
            ptr = arr1;
        } else if(arrName == "B") {
            ptr = arr2;
        }
        privateMethod1(ptr, name);
    }

    void myPublicMethod2() {
        auto i = vect1.begin();
        for(; i < vect1.end(); i++) {
            doPrint(i->arr, i->name);
            // here the link between pointers broken,
            // doPrint() shows me random characters
        }
    }

private:
    void privateMethod1(uint8_t const * ptr, std::string name) {
        // this method receives pointer correctly, so I can doPrint(ptr)
        s1 myStruct;
        myStruct.name = name;
        myStruct.arr = ptr;
        vect1.push_back(myStruct);
    }

    void doPrint(const uint8_t arr[], std::string name) {
        for(uint16_t i = 0; i < sizeof(*arr); i++) {
            if(name.length() > 0) {
                std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
            } else {
                std::cout << "No name\n";
            }
        }
    }
};


int main() {
    A ca;
    ca.myPublicMethod("A", "");
    ca.myPublicMethod("B", "image");
    ca.myPublicMethod2();
    return 0;
}
```

This code is just a small part of a project (main code). I found imposible / unnecessary to post whole project because there are lots of unnecessary stuffs that definitely will require a bunch of time to understand.

Initially I thought there were a problem with a pointers, particularly in A::myPublicMethod, that creates *ptr, that then being transferred to A::privateMethod1 to store in vect1. I was wrong thinking there is a mistake while saving / transferring to vect1. Lately I didn't find any changes for vect1 in a main code. 
Vector vas created well, the problem was in method doPrint, particularly in if(name.length() > 0)... So again, I had to stick to the logic of main code without inventing an example which was a lil far from reality.

In conclusion thanks to @paulmckenzie who indirectly gave me a reason to stop thinking in pointers. It would help me a lot if someone just confirmed that following my first example, pointers are logically correct.

Cheers,